# Trouble mapping YAML to Java Object

Tags: java, yaml

I am new to Yaml, and not sure exactly how to map this simple Yaml to a Java Object. Basically, the serialization is all done, I just need a Java object that models the Yaml.

This is my Yaml:

```
thriftResources:
  - class: MissionWork
    jsonIdField: id
    jsonResource: test
  - class: MissionResource
    jsonIdField: uuid
    jsonResource: test2
```

So far, I have this as my class:

```
@Valid
public ThriftResourceConfiguration thriftResources = new ThriftResourceConfiguration();

public class ThriftResourceConfiguration{
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    ????
}
```

What I am looking for is what the Java object should look like in order to map correctly.

Comment: So basically the question is "how do I deserialize yaml in Java"? Seems a bit broad, no? You haven't even mentioned what ser/de tool you're using. (And if you haven't picked one yet and are asking for a suggestion, then I'd hope a 12k-rep user would know that that's off topic at SO...)

Comment: No no, just what the yaml object would like in java. Sorry, made more clear. And yea, i realize this is such a basic question. Its been driving me nuts trying to deseralize this thing. But I am using Katahrsis for this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Katahrsis. If they don't do some sort of magic bean-style deserialization, I would expect you'd just get back a List containing Maps of String -> String in the yaml you provided above, and then it'd be up to you to turn that list of maps into a list of whatever Java classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

YamlBeans can be used to serialize and deserialize Java object graphs to and from YAML.

http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/

```
YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("contact.yml"));
Object object = reader.read();
System.out.println(object);
Map map = (Map)object;
System.out.println(map.get("address"));
```